# OmniAuth get token cannot parse response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I have a ruby on rails application that wanted to implement facebook login into.

Added the following gems to my gemfile

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

When i try to login with facebook i get this error (Yes, it looks kind of malformed):

```
OAuth2::Error:
:     {"access_token":"<actual token removed>","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5740}
```

Extracted source (lib/oauth2/client.rb:135:in `get_token'):

```
  raise Error.new(response) if options[:raise_errors] && !(response.parsed.is_a?(Hash) && response.parsed['access_token'])
  AccessToken.from_hash(self, response.parsed.merge(access_token_opts))
end
```

I have debugged it down to `response.parsed` is not an Hash, but looks like this:

```
{{\"access_token\":\"<actual token removed>\",\"token_type\":\"bearer\",\"expires_in\":5361}"=>nil}
```

If you look closely, it looks like the `response.parsed` hash is messed up. Somehow the actual response hash has become a `key => nil` like a nested hash.

Anyone know's why this happens?

Ruby 2.3.0

Comment: Which version of Rails and are you sure your gems for `omniauth` and `omniauth-facebook` are up to date?

Comment: Rails (4.2.1),  omniauth (1.6.1), omniauth-facebook (1.4.0), omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.3)

Comment: I read somewhere that it might be because oauth2 reads the response from facebook as a string and not json .. Could that be the case ?

Comment: Rasmus try updating your omniauth-facebook gem (I'm using 4.0.0) and omniauth-oauth2 (I'm on 1.3.1), because I'm not seeing any error now, nor before when I was in Rails 4.2.1

Comment: Michael that actually worked. I dunno why gem was not updated to 4.0.0 when i used gem update.

Comment: Rasmus, the fact that you can't type my name correctly does explain a lot I guess :x

Comment: take it easy man! :x

Comment: was just kidding man, I thought since I took the time to read your question and offer you a solution I was entitled to make a little bit of fun, just that lol

Comment: No worries ;-) And thank you!